# Safely delete and re-create a Kaka topic with the Admin API, without TopicExistsException

Tags: java, apache-kafka

My use-case is preparing the environment for automated testing against a local Kafka Cluster. Taking inspiration from Kafka's own tests ([this, for instance](http://(for%20instance%20https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/AbstractResetIntegrationTest.java#L193))), I want to delete a topic and re-create it. Since I'm not running the broker embedded in the test jvm, I need to use the Admin API to connect to the running broker.

The code is roughly as follows:

```java
admin.deleteTopics(listWithTopicName).all().get();
probeUntil(() -> {
  doesNotContain(admin.listTopics().names().get(), listWithTopicName);
});
admin.createTopics(new NewTopic(topicName, ...));
```

The problem is that the call to `createTopics` throws a TopicExistsException such as

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'test-topic' already exists.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at clojure.core$deref_future.invokeStatic(core.clj:2300)
    at clojure.core$deref.invokeStatic(core.clj:2320)
    at clojure.core$deref.invoke(core.clj:2306)
    at playground$create_topics.invokeStatic(playground.clj:113)
    at playground$create_topics.invoke(playground.clj:108)
    at playground$delete_and_recreate_topics.invokeStatic(playground.clj:120)
    at playground$delete_and_recreate_topics.invoke(playground.clj:118)
    at playground$eval26601.invokeStatic(playground.clj:141)
    at playground$eval26601.invoke(playground.clj:141)
    (snip)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:40)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'test-topic' already exists.
```

I expected the probe between `delete` and `create` to avoid the problem, but it seems even though `listTopics` is returning a list without the recently deleted topic, a subsequent call to `createTopic` for the same name will fail with `TopicExistsException`. If I insert a `Thread.sleep(100)` call between `deleteTopics` and `createTopics`, the problem goes away.

Inspecting broker logs, I see a series of logs related to the delete operation, but none related to the create call.

BTW, the kafka tests I'm basing my logic on do similar operations, but the probing is based on iterating registered topics via zookeeper, which would require adding more dependencies and complexity for my use case.

Comment: Topic deletion is eventually consistent

Comment: @OneCricketeer Did you mean that even though, I use the KafkaAdminClient to delete, and even if its Future succeeds that I have to wait for a period of time for the topic deletion to actually happen? link: https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/KafkaAdminClient.html

Comment: @Gayal AFAIK, the Future returning just means the controller broker accepted the request. Not that every replica is fully gone from disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no way to improve probing in order to avoid the race condition, so the solution was to detect the specific case in the try block, and retry a couple of times. Roughly something like the following:

```java
void deleteAndRecreate(String topicName, Admin admin) {
  admin.deleteTopics(listWithTopicName).all().get();
  probeUntil(() -> { 
    !topicExists(topicName, admin);
  });
  tryCreateTopic(topicName, ..., admin, 0);
}

boolean topicExists(String topicName, Admin admin) {
  return admin.listTopics().names().get().contains(asList(topicName));
}

void tryCreateTopic(String topicName, ... Admin admin, int attempts) {
  try {
    admin.createTopics(asList(new NewTopic(topicName,...))).all().get()
    probeUntil(() -> topicIsCorrect(topicName, ...));
  } catch (ExcecutionException e) {
    if ((e.getCause() instanceOf TopicExistsException) && !topicExists(topicName, admin) && attempts <= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
      Thread.sleep(30 * attempts);
      tryCreateTopic(...., attempts + 1);
    }
    else {
      throw e;
    } 
  }
}
```

The actual code is in Clojure, so there are probably mistakes in the transliteration to Java, but the basic idea works. Not pretty, but works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have a workaround, asking for each brokers the state of their partition. Then it is the same approach of "waiting until the topic not exists anymore"

Here my topicExists method

```java
  private static boolean topicExists(Admin admin, String topic) {
    try {
      Set<String> existingTopics = admin.listTopics().names().get();
      if (existingTopics.contains(topic)) {
        return true;
      }
      Collection<Node> nodes = admin.describeCluster().nodes().get();
      long partitionRemaining = admin.describeLogDirs(
          nodes.stream().map(Node::id).collect(Collectors.toList()))
          .allDescriptions().get()
          .values()
          .stream()
          .flatMap(perBroker -> perBroker.values().stream())
          .flatMap(perTopic -> perTopic.replicaInfos().entrySet().stream())
          .map(Entry::getKey)
          .map(TopicPartition::topic)
          .filter(topicName -> topicName.equals(topic))
          .count();
      return partitionRemaining > 0;
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }
```